# How to get advertising identifier on IOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, ads, identifier

I'm doing Work light Project, and i need a plugin to get **advertising identifier**, which value not change unless user hard reset them phone.
But because i'm never do IOS before, so i don't know how to get **advertising identifier** on IOS 6,7.
I was try **identifierForVendor**, but it change everytime i reinstall an application.
 Any help for me ? (i do not need push this app to appstore).

Answer (score 14):

To get AdvertisingId of any iOS Device do this :
Only for iOS versions > 6.0

```
#import <AdSupport/ASIdentifierManager.h>
NSUUID *adId = [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier];
NSString *str = [adId UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use advertisingIdentifier?

If you check the documentation 
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012654-CH1-SW4

> Unlike the identifierForVendor property of the UIDevice, the same value is returned to all vendors. This identifier may change—for example, if the user erases the device—so you should not cache it. If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens, for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user has unlocked the device.